# USB extension cord: can give power but modem can't be read

Tags: usb

Problem. 5m usb extension cord can power up a modem but the modem can't be read by the computer. How can we possibly solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 meters is the maximum supported length a USB cable can be.  However, it doesnt mean it is guaranteed to work.  Try it in a different USB port and also try a shorter cable and see if it works.  If it does, then you know the signal is getting lost on the larger cable, or there is to much of a delay in the signal.  If a shorter cable doesnt work, then there is a problem with the modem and/or the USB hub/port its connected to.

Comment: The thing is it was working few days ago and then all of a sudden, the problem emerged. Using a shorter cable solves the problem, though. Would you think it is possible to fix the problem?

Comment: sounds like something is causing interference with the signal.  Is there a new electrical device nearby?

Comment: is this a cable modem?  why not use an Ethernet cable?

Comment: MY modem is a usb plugit. we use the cable extension so that we can place the modem on the part of the house where we can get good signal. 

And to answer your previous question, there is no neew electrical device nearby.

Comment: you may be out of luck on the USB cable...  However, you should be able to increase the wireless range with a high gain antenna sold online and most computer stores.  similar to this http://www.amazon.com/Gain-Wi-Fi-Antenna-RPSMA-Connector/dp/B001E52BFC

Comment: Thank you @Keltari. I  am trying to understand why all of a sudden the usb did not work, though.